# sweet alert 2 gem confirm box redirect to link after pressing ok

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am not sure why ok or cancel doesnt do anything, anyways I want when someone press at ok to redirect it to a link

```
<div class="popup" onclick="sweetalertclick()">
              <p id="center"><%= image_tag "pickup.png" ,width: "80px"%><br>
                <span  onclick="sweetalertclick()"></span>Request a DDS pick u
                </span>
              </p>
            </div>
    <script>
    function sweetalertclick() {
    
    swal({
        title: "Request a DDS",
        text: "Please log in to DDS website to request a pick up, my code is: xxxx. By pressing ok you will link to google.com",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Ok",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false,
      },
      function(isConfirm){
        if (isConfirm) {
          window.location.href = "google.com"
        }
      }
    );
      
    }
    </script>
```

in gem file

```
gem 'rails-assets-sweetalert2', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'sweet-alert2-rails'
gem 'sweet-alert-confirm'
```

in application.js

```
//= require sweetalert2
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require sweet-alert2-rails
//= require cocoon 
//= require sweet-alert-confirm  
//= require_tree .
```

in application.scss

```
 *= require_self
 *= require sweetalert2
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.then()` and then pass the redirection procedure inside that:

Example:

```
function sweetalertclick() {

swal({
    title: 'Request a DDS',
    text: "Please log in to DDS website to request a pick up, my code is: xxxx. By pressing ok you will link to google.com",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Ok",
  }).then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
    if (result) {
      window.location.href = "google.com";
    }
  });
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i can't press ok or cancel

Comment: Can you replicate your error in a JSFiddle and show?

Comment: sweetalert2.js:223 SweetAlert2: Unknown parameter "closeOnConfirm" sweetalert2.js:223 SweetAlert2: Unknown parameter "closeOnCancel"
warn @ sweetalert2.js:223

Comment: Still the same. I updated my question with extra code

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in a JSFiddle please?

Comment: still the same. can't press ok or cancel :s

Comment: It works now after removing this link <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.js"></script>   but the button color and width are not working

Comment: the link is not rendering in heroku. do you know why?

Comment: It's not clickable in heroku

Comment: Please check whether there are any issues in the logs or browser consoles

Comment: Publish as a new question. I'll try to help

Comment: I upgraded my heroku app. Do you think this is the reason?

Comment: Cannot exactly tell. It might be the issue. :)

Comment: Even cancel button is not responding

Comment: I solve it by this bundle exec rake assets:precompile Thank you :)